# openSUSE Leap 42.3: Cannot install Jekyll due to dependency issues

Tags: package-management, opensuse, dependencies, gem

I'm trying to install Jekyll on my Linode server running openSUSE Leap 42.3, but Zypper gives me this error:

```
# zypper install ruby2.1-rubygem-jekyll
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides rubygem(ruby:2.1.0:colorator:0) >= 0.1 needed by ruby2.1-rubygem-jekyll-3.1.6-3.3.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install ruby2.1-rubygem-jekyll-3.1.6-3.3.x86_64
 Solution 2: break ruby2.1-rubygem-jekyll-3.1.6-3.3.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c):
```

If I force-install by selecting solution 2, Jekyll fails because it cannot find the correct version of the `colorator` gem. This occurs even if I install the `ruby2.1-rubygem-colorator` package.

Is this an issue with the Jekyll package, or is the problem upstream?

I don't want to use the `gem` command directly because this could result in conflicts with files installed by the package manager. I'd rather use one and only one way to install applications at the system level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with the package. The best solution right now is to leave a bug report on [SUSE's bugzilla](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Submitting_bug_reports) and install Jekyll from the [sources](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/).

Double check when you are installing Ruby to see if colorator is properly installed when you do it manually.

Comment: A bug report already exists on the openSUSE Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1030036

Comment: well, unless you know how to build jekyll manually, you'll have to wait, but you can leave a comment in bugzilla and see what happens :)